# What is the meaning of 为 in 老有所为

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the title of an article from [人民网](http://opinion.people.com.cn/n1/2023/1214/c431649-40138954.html).

> 人民来论: 老有所学、老有所乐，更可老有所为

The first part of the article is:

随着我国人口老龄化的不断加剧，各地积极推动老年教育，以丰富多彩的活动形式助力老年人老有所学、老有所乐，让老人们生活变得充实、快乐。

为 seems to correspond with: 让老人们生活变得充实、快乐

I think they mean:

更可老有所为
but also, old folks have something to achieve

Not sure how 为 means 'achieve' maybe that should be 'something to live for'

What is the meaning of 为 in:

> 更可老有所为

Answer (score 4):

为 is a multi-meaning word,
it can be 行为 = Behavior,

or 作为 = Accomplishment,
which is the meaning in the paragraph.
"To let elders have something to accomplish."

Answer (score 2):

为 in 老有所为 means 作为--achievement. But in the context, I think this phrase can be better understood as "Old people have something meaningful to engage in in their life."

**So your interpretation is right here.** Please note that '为' can have diverse meanings in different contexts.